# Create 5 Equal Outcomes By Changing Markings On 6-sided Fair Die

Tags: probability

I found this question years ago in a Times Of India Newspaper Puzzle Column called Mindsport curated by Mukul Sharma but haven't found the answer yet:

A 6-sided fair die of course has 6 equally possible outcomes because there are 6 different markings on each side. Now I could easily change this to 3 equally possible outcomes simply by  making the same 3 markings twice (1,1,2,2,3,3) - I have changed the probability of a 1,2 or 3 occurring to 1/3. I can also change this to 2 equally possible outcomes by making the same 2 markings thrice (1,1,1,2,2,2) - I have changed the probability of a 1 or 2 occurring to 1/2.

The question is: Can I change the probability of a 6-sided fair die to 1/5. That is, the outcome must be that the die gives out a 1,2,3,4 or 5 with equal probability of 1/5.

You can use any markings, formula, calculation etc. on each of the 6 sides. For example one side could say "Add the other 5 numbers" or "Take the square root of the number on the opposite side".

tl;dr: I need 5 equal outcomes from a fair 6-sided die using any markings you wish to make on the 6 sides.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Just to clarify, there should not be any "Throw Again" cases. I should be able to throw a 6-sided die and *every single time* it should give me one of 5 equally probable outcomes. Of course, your outcomes don't even have to be the numbers 1-5. As long as they are unique one can easily map your 5 unique outcomes to 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like more of a lateral thinking puzzle. If you can't do multiple rolls, I suppose you could mark up side #6 with some hypothetical directional indicator that didn't affect the fairness of the die and then if that side came up you could judge which value from 1-5 it represented by its orientation (rotated about an axis going through the center of the die and perpendicular to the table).

Comment: I like this answer.  Plot a set of lines radiating out from the center of the table in fifths of the circle and put a pointer on one side of the die.

Comment: Very interesting answer - wonder if there's a way to make it point at exactly one of the other 5 numbers?

Comment: I think I just might have found a way by extending this idea. Draw a pointer on the 6th side. Mark/imagine the die-throwing-area into 5 equal sides with each numbered 1-5 and if the pointer-marked side comes face up, it will point to one of the pre-decided regions numbered 1-5.

Comment: Why not draw a pointer on all 6 sides?

Comment: Henry: Because guaranteeing their orientation/direction will always give a probability of 1/5 no matter which side comes up is a non-trivial problem. With a pointer on only one side, any orientation/direction can guarantee this.

Answer (score 3):

Change the markings on one of the sides to "**Throw again!**"

Comment: That was my first thought too, but decided against posting since I'm curious if there's a way to "simulate" possibly countably many throws in a single throw.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry, but I don't see how that solves the problem. I need it to say exactly one of the following: 1,2,3,4 or 5. Every time. With equal probability.

Comment: @Prash - it solves the problem.  Your requirement, which is stronger than the question, is impossible as the possible events each throw have probabilities of $\frac06, \frac16, \frac26, \frac36, \frac46, \frac56, \frac66$, none of which are $\frac15$.

Answer (score 2):

```
Paint faces 1 through 5 with the numbers 1 through 5.
Paint the 6th face with the math expression: ceil(rand() * 5),
where rand() produces rational numbers in the range (0, 1]
```

Comment: I suspect OP won't accept this, but it is fun.  You need something else to do the rand()

Comment: That's not a math expression, it's a programming expression.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to leave one side blank and if you get that one you call for a reroll.  Keep rolling until you don't get the blank.  Unfortunately you can't guarantee a result in any given number of throws, but on average it will only take $\frac 65$ to get one.

You cannot be sure to get a result with six sided dice and insist that all results be equally probable.  This is because for $n$ rolls there are $6^n$ possible results and this is not divisible by $5$.  Contrast with wanting $2$ or $3$ results-they both divide into $6$.  If you wanted $4$ results you could do it with $2$ rolls because $4$ divides $36$

Comment: Need the result from every single throw (no "rolling again"). But you can use any markings/formulae/calcualtions on each side - need not be just numbers. But each throw should give me 1-5 with equal probability.

Comment: I showed why that cannot be done. Changing markings doesn't change that.